# How can I set an ID with prefix and increment decimal values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to adapt a spreasheet application I developed.

The current application uses userforms to input user information in multiple worksheets. However, instead of importing all that data to a SQL Database, I was wondering if it was possible to add a single "rows" one by one.

Two of the columns on one of the sheets, has an ID that is set with a prefix (something like 080219001) and another column has incremental values going in a sequence like 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1 and so on.

Here's the code I have for one of the sheets

```vb
'Open the destination file in case it was closed
Set carb = grids.Sheets("Carbonation") 'Worksheet the data will be exported to
Set etiqc = grids.Sheets("Carb Labels") 'Worksheet used to print Carbonation labels

'Last Filled Row and First Empty Row
FR = carb.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ER = FR + 1

'Data exported to GridsDB.xslx
carb.Range("B" & ER).Value = Requip.Text 'Equipment reference
carb.Range("C" & ER).Value = Lmembranes.Text 'Membranes lot
carb.Range("E" & ER).Value = Val(Density.Value) 'Density of the carbonation
carb.Range("F" & ER).Value = Val(txt_temperature.Value) 'Carbonation temperature
carb.Range("G" & ER).Value = Val(txt_humidity.Value) 'Carbonation humidity
carb.Range("H" & ER).Value = puidc.Text 'PUID
carb.Range("I" & ER).Value = Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") 'Date of carbonation
carb.Range("J" & ER).Value = Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy") 'Date for comparison purposes
carb.Range("K" & ER).Value = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss") 'Time of carbonation
carb.Range("L" & ER).Value = txt_comments.Text 'Carbonation comments
carb.Range("M" & ER).Value = Val(mnok.Value) 'Qty NOK membranes
carb.Range("N" & ER).Value = motive.Text

'Carbonation ID
If carb.Range("J" & ER).Value = carb.Range("J" & FR).Value Then
    carb.Range("A" & ER).Value = carb.Range("A" & FR).Value + 1
Else
    carb.Range("A" & ER).Value = Replace(Date, "/", "") & "001"
End If

'Carbonation Number
If carb.Range("J" & ER).Value = carb.Range("J" & FR).Value Then
    carb.Range("D" & ER).Value = carb.Range("D" & FR).Value + 1
Else
    carb.Range("D" & ER).Value = 1
End If
End Sub
```

I'm using this code to input user data into "Carbonation" sheet.

I've done some tests and managed to import the data directly to a test Table in SQL. My only issue is the "Carbonation ID" and "Carbonation Number".

I'd appreciate suggestions regarding this.

Comment: The row() function is fairly useful for incrementing numbers. Alternatively, have a variable, I, starting at 1, and every time you use it increases by 1

Comment: Are these IDs meant to reliably identify individual records (and then used in foreign key constraints and lookups), or they're just record metadata? I would warmly recommend leaving the unique ID handling to an `identity` column in a SQL Server table. Anything you can cook up in Excel is going to be flawed, and when things go wrong (note: *when*, not *if*), they will go *horribly* wrong. Often all it takes is a single row getting deleted. Excel isn't a relational database engine, SQL Server is.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes. Thuese IDs are meant to identify individual records.
I would leave ID handling to SQL as long as I could add a prefix.
I'm trying to move away from Excel because honestly, I'm tired of Excel. But I still need a userform so people can input data.